# How to do a Win 8 parallel install?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, sony-vaio

I've acquired a license for Windwos 8 but my Sony support says that my Sony laptop is not compatible. I think that it will run Windows 8 and I've heard that it's possible to do a "parallel install" and keep Windows 7. **How can I do this?**

And if the parallel install works, can I then remove Windwos 7?

Will my 3G modem with builtin SIM card have support in Windows 8? I have no "strange" peripherals, only standard Sony Vaio VPCSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Sony says that it's not compatible, then you will have a hard time finding the propper drivers. You probably wont get any 3G modem driver for Windows 8 (you can use the Windows 7 one with the compatibility mode (Right click > Solve compatibility issies)).

Remember that you usually get a Windows 8 upgrade version that doesnt let you activate the product if you perform a clean installation.